# com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message had invalid UTF-8 when parsing protobuf bytes

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am trying to convert json to proto message object and sent to server bytes. In advance I don't know class of Protobuf. But server parse my bytes and throw exception:

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message had invalid UTF-8.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidUtf8(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:172)
    at com.google.protobuf.Utf8$UnsafeProcessor.decodeUtf8(Utf8.java:1388)
    at com.google.protobuf.Utf8.decodeUtf8(Utf8.java:341)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readStringRequireUtf8(CodedInputStream.java:811)
    at ru.nspk.mirage.fetch.protobuf.FetchRequestProto$ConfigInfo.<init>(FetchRequestProto.java:1260)
    at ru.nspk.mirage.fetch.protobuf.FetchRequestProto$ConfigInfo$1.parsePartialFrom(FetchRequestProto.java:2004)
    at ru.nspk.mirage.fetch.protobuf.FetchRequestProto$ConfigInfo$1.parsePartialFrom(FetchRequestProto.java:1998)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:883)
    at ru.nspk.mirage.fetch.protobuf.FetchRequestProto$RequestPayload.<init>(FetchRequestProto.java:133)
    at ru.nspk.mirage.fetch.protobuf.FetchRequestProto$RequestPayload$1.parsePartialFrom(FetchRequestProto.java:1146)
    at ru.nspk.mirage.fetch.protobuf.FetchRequestProto$RequestPayload$1.parsePartialFrom(FetchRequestProto.java:1140)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:158)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:191)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:203)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:208)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:48)
    at ru.nspk.mirage.fetch.protobuf.FetchRequestProto$RequestPayload.parseFrom(FetchRequestProto.java:444)
    at ru.nspk.rx.base.protobuf.ProtoMain.main(ProtoMain.java:39)
```

I tried to reproduce the error local and got the same exception

```
        String strJson = Files.readString(Paths.get("file.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("strJson::: " + strJson);

        Message message = ProtoJsonUtil.fromJson(strJson);
        System.out.println("ProtoFromJson::: " + message);

        FetchRequestProto.RequestPayload payload = FetchRequestProto.RequestPayload.parseFrom(message.toByteArray()); **//error**
        System.out.println("ProtoFromBytes::: " + payload);

    public static Message fromJson(String json) throws IOException {
        Struct.Builder structBuilder = Struct.newBuilder();
        JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(json, structBuilder); 
        return structBuilder.build();
    }
```

If i use method where i specify a class then everythink ok. But i don't have any information about which class server uses.

```
    public static <T extends Message> T fromJson(String json, Class<?> clazz) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Message.Builder builder = (Message.Builder) clazz.getMethod("newBuilder").invoke(null);
        JsonFormat.parser().ignoringUnknownFields().merge(json, builder);
        return (T) builder.build();
    }
```

My Json

```
{
  "configInfo": {
    "configVersion": "1.0.0",
    "configGroup": "group",
    "iuk": 1,
    "ium": 1
  },
  "deviceInfo": {
    "deviceId": "0x12312",
    "deviceInfo": "info"
  }
}
```

Proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package mrg.fetch;
option java_package = "com.nsk.mrg.fetch.protobuf";
option java_outer_classname = "FetchRequestProto";
import "device_info.proto";
import "log.proto";

message RequestPayload {
  ConfigInfo config_info = 1;
  DeviceInfo device_info = 2;
  optional bytes sv_hash = 3;
  optional DeviceLog device_log = 4;
}

message ConfigInfo {
  string config_version = 1;
  string config_group = 2;
  uint32 iuk = 3;
  uint32 ium = 4;
}
```

Can i convert json to protobuf bytes without information about class which will be used during conversion in protobuf?

Answer (score 1):

> Can i convert json to protobuf bytes without information about class which will be used during conversion in protobuf?

No. Fundamentally, protobuf binary wire format uses field *numbers* whereas JSON includes only *names* for properties. The `Struct` representation is just "a protobuf representation of a JSON object" - it's not "the protobuf binary wire format representation of a JSON object conforming to a specific protobuf message schema".

You can parse the JSON as a `Struct` and serialize those bytes, as you're already doing, then when you're in a context where you know what message type you want to parse, you can parse the bytes as a `Struct`, convert that back to JSON, then parse that JSON as `RequestPayload` or whatever... it would probably be simpler just to transport the JSON as a string though.